# What sort of gradients do you get when you substitute an x value into the derived function?

Tags: calculus

If you have a derived function and you substitute an x value into that derived function does that automatically give you both the gradient of a point on the curve and the tangent?

I'm a bit confused about this as my textbook says that the gradient of the tangent and the gradient of the point on the curve are the same but doesn't say if using the derived function is appropriate for finding both.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The only way your proposition can be valid is the following: the "gradient" interpreted as the derivative of the parametrized curve $d_0=\nabla F(t_0)$ evaluated at some point $x_0=F(t_0)$ of a curve $\mathscr{C}:t \in \mathbb{R} \to x=F(t) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is only the direction of the tangent at that point, it is a vector.

The tangent $\mathscr{L}_0$ is a line, a set $t \in \mathbb{R} \to x=x_0+td_0 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ made from the point selected $x_0$ and the gradient $d_0$ (its direction) multiplied by an arbitrary constant $t$. It is a vectorial function.

Strictly speaking a curve do not have gradient, a *surface* $\mathscr{S}: x' \in \mathbb{R}^{n-1} \to x=G(x') in \mathbb{R}^n$. In this case, the tangent is not defined, and your proposition is only valid when the tangent is at the *maximum descent* direction.